# fabric.js disable drawing on black pixel

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am making a drawing app in fabric.js.
I want to ignore the black area of image to be colored in. 
Any suggestions please????
[Click the link for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCOGY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the image as overlay.Please check here:http://jsfiddle.net/mariusturcu93/s5wxbcde/19/
**JS**

```
 var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    canvas.backgroundColor = "blue";
    canvas.isDrawingMode=1;
    canvas.setOverlayImage('https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/fantendo/images/6/6e/Small-mario.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/381?cb=20120718024112', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
        width: canvas.width,
        height: canvas.height
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the good solution. :) 
But it's temporarily drawing pixels on the image. Is there any way to avoid that temporary pixel on the image?

Comment: You can check here:http://jsfiddle.net/mariusturcu93/s5wxbcde/49/                             I extended the _render method and onMouseMove from fabric.PencilBrush and I redrawn the overlaybackground.

Comment: Hi brother!
Can you please help me out in another simple problem?
I want to apply an image pattern to a simple png image like shirt using only fabric.js. I tried a lot but couldn't make it working.
Any suggestion would be helpful... Thanks ^_^